# Oracle 10g: parsing 2 columns merging duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm having a table with 3 columns:
`DATE_A`, `DATE_B` and `ISSUE`
`DATE_A` and `DATE_B` can be filled in 3 possible ways:
either both have a value, or only one have, as shown here:

```
DATE_A    |  DATE_B   | ISSUE
----------+-----------+-----------
20130301  | 20140101  | bla 
20150801  | null      | foo
null      | 20180701  | bar
```

I need to parse this table to populate a new table, with DATE_A and DATE_B populating both a single column `DATE_M`.
If the `DATE_A` (or `DATE_B`) value to insert into `DATE_M` already exists in `DATE_M`, then the source `ISSUE` must be appended with the existing `DATE_M` `ISSUE`. The example below show the principle.

**Example**

*Source*

```
DATE_A    |  DATE_B   | ISSUE
----------+-----------+-----------
20130301  | 20140101  | bla1
20150801  | null      | foo1
null      | 20180701  | bar
20130301  | 20150101  | bla2
20150801  | null      | foo2
```

*Destination*

```
DATE_M    | ISSUE
----------+-----------
20130301  | bla1; bla2
20140101  | bla1
20150801  | foo1; foo2
20150101  | bla2
20180701  | bar
```

**Question**

Is it possible to write a query doing that or should a stored procedure be written ? If a single query can, what could it be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a `union all` of the date values and string aggregation.  `listagg()` was introduced in 11g, but you can use `wm_concat()`:

```
select dte, wm_concat(issue) as issues
from ((select date_a as dte, issue from t where date_a is not null) union all
      (select date_b, issue from t where date_b is not null)
     ) di
group by dte
order by dte;
```

Comment: wow. Thanks Gordon, it work perfectly! Much appreciated. Marked answered and up voted!