# Oracle 10g: Inserting multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-insert

I'm having the following [select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040922/oracle-10g-parsing-2-columns-merging-duplicates) :

```
select dte, wm_concat(issue) as issues
from ((select date_a as dte, issue from t where date_a is not null) union all
      (select date_b, issue from t where date_b is not null)
     ) di
group by dte
order by dte;
```

that returns multiple rows such as:

```
DTE        | ISSUES
-----------+---------
01/JUN/91  | EE
01/JUN/03  | EE
01/JAN/06  | HH
01/AUG/06  | EE
01/AUG/08  | EE,HS,HE
```

I would like insert these records into a table.

**Question**

How should I write the insert statement ? Should I use a cursor as it seems INSERT can process one row at time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the select as the source for the insert:

```
insert into some_table (dte, issues)
select dte, wm_concat(issue) as issues
from (
   select date_a as dte, issue 
   from t 
   where date_a is not null
   union all
   select date_b, issue 
   from t 
   where date_b is not null
) di
group by dte;
```

There is no need to put the individual queries of a UNION between parentheses.

Comment: Thanks! it works. Marked correct and up voted. How can I add in this insert a value `i_ref` passed to the fonction that execute this insert ? In others words, for each insert made, `i_ref ` must be inserted too. Let me know if I should raise a separate question.