# Oracle 10g: insert multiples values from inner select, along with constants

Tags: oracle10g, sql-insert

I'm having a [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058972/oracle-10g-inserting-multiple-rows/52059014#52059014) returning multiple rows.
These row are inserted into a table as follow:

```
insert into some_table (dte, issues)
select dte, issues
from ( .. ) di
group by dte;
```

During the insert, I would like to the following values:

- `i_ref` coming from the function parameter
- Any others value (eg `v_tot`) coming from another functions calls.

The code below summarize the situation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a_funct (
    i_ref   VARCHAR2, 
) RETURN NUMBER --0= no err reported, 1 = err reported
 AS
    v_tot NUMBER;

BEGIN

    v_tot  := another_funct();

    --
    -- v_tot and i_ref must be inserted too
    --
    insert into some_table (dte, issues)
    select dte, issues
    from ( .. ) di
    group by dte;


    RETURN 1;
END a_funct;
```

**Question**

How to transform the insert statement above to add the constants ?

Comment: `select dte, issues, v_tot ...`

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name !