# Oracle 10g: truncate string

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm having a query that append a string value from multiple rows and insert the result in a new table.

I would like to limit the String length that is inserted.

**Question**

What is the best way to achieve that :
Should I use `SUBSTR` or `SUBSTRB` or is there a better way ?

Comment: Define the column to have a fixed limit, such as `varchar2(10)` or `char(10)`.

Comment: You still need to truncate your aggregated string so it fits into the size-restricted column in the table though, to avoid run-time errors; and whether you should use `substr` or `substrb` depends on whether that size is restricted in characters or bytes (i.e. `varchar2(10 char)` or `varchar2(10 byte)`).

Comment: How are you building the string? If you are appending to your string in a loop, I would stop the iteration when the max size is reached, instead of building a long string and then truncating it.

Comment: @Aleksej you absolutly right on that. The string is built on the fly as follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040922/oracle-10g-parsing-2-columns-merging-duplicates. Ideally, I would have avoid unecessary append, but it will change completely the query. I guess there are no turn-around beside break the query in fragements ?

Comment: @AlexPoole That the problem I wanted to avoid. Is `SUBSTR` the way to go ? (at the cost of building a string for nothing (above the limit) ?

Comment: Editing that kind of query to stop appending once reached a given length could be not so easy, so I would use a substr to limit the string length to the size you need

Answer (score 7):

Using SQL you can use [`SUBSTR` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) to get the character limit

```
SELECT SUBSTR (test_string, 0, 10) FROM table_name
```

E.g.

```
SELECT  SUBSTR ('Testing1/testing2', 0, 10) FROM dual
```

Using [`LENGTH` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm), you will be able to ascertain the count of the string

```
SELECT  LENGTH ('Testing1/testing2') FROM dual
```

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, yes, 0 is treated as 1 for the start index.